# Visual Studio for mac: how to create new git branch

Tags: git, visual-studio-mac

In Visual Studio for mac I connected and checked out a project from git repository. I call context menu by clicking on the project and see this

[image]

[image]

Could someone tell me where to create a new branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to switch to a branch it has to be available locally. If it is not available locally then do the following to setup a local branch:

1. From the main menu select Version Control - Manage Branches and Remotes
2. Select the Remote Sources tab.
3. Find the branch in the list. You will need to expand the origin item.
4. Select the branch and click Track in Local Branch.

Now you should be able to switch to that branch from the Solution window or by using the dialog that is currently open, from the Branches tab.